# Techniques for binding object properties to Sheet Cells

Tags: excel, vba

Edit:
The three main things I'm looking to accomplish here are:

- To be able to encapsulate properties/methods into a class (easy enough)
- Use excel ranges as a user input for users to manipulate class property values.
- (bonus) Send user changes back up to a database.

---

I've been playing with the idea of building something in vba that would allow me to bind an object's property(ies) to a Range. Basically turning a cell into a bound control.

Some basic requirements I might be after include:

- A change to the object property would update the cell value
- A change to the cell would update the object property
- The object property may be bound/unbound without losing the value of the property.

My initial thought is to build a `BindRange` class that simply gets its value from a range and sets its value to that range.

BindRange.cls:

```
Option Explicit

Private p_BoundCell As Range

Public Property Get Value() As String
    If Me.IsBound Then Value = p_BoundCell.Value
End Property

Public Property Let Value(Val As String)
    If Me.IsBound Then p_BoundCell.Value = Val
End Property

Public Property Get IsBound() As Boolean
    If BoundToDeletedCell Then
        Set p_BoundCell = Nothing
    End If

    IsBound = Not (p_BoundCell Is Nothing)

End Property

Public Sub Bind(Cell As Range)
    Set p_BoundCell = Cell(1, 1)
End Sub


Private Function BoundToDeletedCell() As Boolean
    Dim sTestAddress As String

    On Error Resume Next
TRY:
    If p_BoundCell Is Nothing Then
        Exit Function
        '// returns false
    End If

    sTestAddress = p_BoundCell.Address

    If Err.Number = 424 Then 'object required
        BoundToDeletedCell = True
    End If

End Function
```

Then, I can set up my custom object with a pair of fields to manage the updates. I would also need a method to expose setting the range to be bound.

TestObject.cls:

```
Option Explicit

Private p_BindId As BindRange
Private p_Id As String

Public Property Get Id() As String

    If p_BindId.IsBound Then
        p_Id = p_BindId.Value
    End If

    Id = p_Id

End Property
Public Property Let Id(Val As String)

    p_Id = Val

    If p_BindId.IsBound Then
        p_BindId.Value = p_Id
    End If

End Property

Public Sub Id_Bind(Cell As Range)
    p_BindId.Bind Cell
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set p_BindId = New BindRange
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set p_BindId = Nothing
End Sub
```

This could be annoying because any property I want to make "Bindable" I'll have to manage Get/Set and Bind for each. I'm also not too sure if this will cause any memory issues: making class-properties with variant typed values....

Also considering building a service-like class that keeps track of objects and their bound ranges in a dictionary-like structure?

Anyways, just curious if anyone has done something like this before or if you have any thoughts on how you might design this.

Comment: Seems like a lot of overhead if you wanted a generic approach which could be applied across instances of different classes. You could maybe make it skinnier using `CallByName` to avoid having to hard-code property names, but you still have to manage both directions for updates, which means you also need listeners for worksheet events.

Comment: @TimWilliams I hadn't heard of CallByName before. I think this will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: guys, why the down votes? No one else is curious how you might do something like this in excel? Or it just can't be done well?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable enough question to me - I guess some people may have judged it "too broad"

Comment: @ArcherBird: it's a good question, IMHO.

Comment: Why bind to an object?  Why not to an ADO Recordset?  Do you have much business logic that you were planning to put into the class?  ADO.Recordsets can be written to worksheet very fast and ought to be closer to something to passed back to database.  Using a worksheet as a datastore can be achieved with Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 oledb driver, and I have written a blog post here https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/10/vba-microsoftaceoledb120-details.html

Comment: @SMeaden Thanks for your comment and link. ADO recordset is definitely what I had in mind for getting and sending from/to the database. In my case there IS a lot of logic that is best encapsulated into classes. So, I was thinking along the lines of: user changes/inputs to a cell -> business logic/rules happen -> changes passed along to the DB.

Comment: Well, you could still pack business logic into a VBA class and have it operate on an ADO Recordset,  Kind of makes it functional programming.

Comment: @SMeaden so something like having a private recordset in the class, and updating the corresponding field with property values, etc?

Comment: Pass in the recordset as a parameter to a class method,( actually could make it a standard module).

Answer (score 4):

Binding individual cells to properties would be very cumbersome.  I think a better technique would be to create a table to act as a property sheet and a `PropertySheetWatcher` that raise a `PropertyChange` event.

Let's say for instance that we wanted to create a simple game on a userform call Stack OverKill.  Our game will have its Hero Class and multiple Enemies classes (e.g. Turtle, Rhino, Wolf).  Although each class has its own business logic they all share common properties (Name, HP, ClassName, Left, Right ...etc).  Naturally, since they all sure the same basic set of properties they should all Implement a common Interface (e.g. `CharacterInterface`).  The beauty of this is they can all share the same Property Sheet Table.

### Mock Property Sheet Table

[image: Property Sheet Table Image]

### PropertySheetWatcher:Class

```
Private WithEvents ws As Worksheet
Public Table As ListObject
Public Event PropertyChange(ByVal PropertyName As String, Value As Variant)

Public Sub Init(ByRef PropertySheetTable As ListObject)
    Set ws = PropertySheetTable.Parent
    Set Table = PropertySheetTable
End Sub

Private Sub ws_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim PropertyName As String
    If Not Intersect(Target, Table.DataBodyRange) Then
        PropertyName = Intersect(Target.EntireColumn, Table.HeaderRowRange).Value
        RaiseEvent PropertyChange(PropertyName, Target.Value)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateProperty(ByVal PropertyName As String, Name As String, Value As Variant)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim RowIndex As Long
    RowIndex = Table.ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange.Find(Name).Row
    Table.ListColumns(PropertyName).DataBodyRange.Cells(RowIndex).Value = Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

### Hero:Class

```
Implements CharacterInterface
Private Type Members
    Name As String
    HP As Single
    ClassName As String
    Left As Single
    Right As Single
    Top As Single
    Bottom As Single
    Direction  As Long
    Speed  As Single
End Type
Private m As Members

Public WithEvents Watcher As PropertySheetWatcher

Private Sub Watcher_PropertyChange(ByVal PropertyName As String, Value As Variant)
    Select Case PropertyName
    Case "Speed"
        Speed = Value
    Case "HP"
    '....More Code
    End Select
    
End Sub

Public Property Get Speed() As Single
    Speed = m.Speed
End Property

Public Property Let Speed(ByVal Value As Single)
    m.Speed = Speed
    Watcher.UpdateProperty "Speed", m.Name, Value
End Property

Private Property Get CharacterInterface_Speed() As Single
    CharacterInterface_Speed = Speed
End Property

Private Property Let CharacterInterface_Speed(ByVal Value As Single)
    Speed = Value
End Property
```

The classes above give are a quick muck-up of how the notification system can be implemented.  But wait there is more!!!

Look how easy it is to setup a Factory to reproduce all of out Characters based off the saved setting.

### CharacterFactory:Class

```
Function AddCharacters(Watcher As PropertySheetWatcher) As CharacterInterface
    Dim Table As ListObject
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim RowIndex As Long
    
    With Table
        data = .DataBodyRange.Value
        
        For RowIndex = 1 To UBound(data)
            Select Case data(RowIndex, .ListColumns("Class").Index)
            Case "Hero"
                Set AddCharacters = AddCharacter(New Hero, Table, RowIndex)
            Case "Turtle"
                Set AddCharacters = AddCharacter(New Turtle, Table, RowIndex)
            Case "Rhino"
                Set AddCharacters = AddCharacter(New Rhino, Table, RowIndex)
            Case "Wolf"
                Set AddCharacters = AddCharacter(New Wolf, Table, RowIndex)
            End Select
        Next
    End With
End Function

Private Function AddCharacter(Character As CharacterInterface, Table As ListObject, RowIndex As Long) As Object
    With Character
        .Speed = Table.ListColumns("Speed").DataBodyRange.Cells(RowIndex).Value
        '....More Coe
    End With
    Set AddCharacter = Character
End Function
```

It may seem like I wrote a lot of original content but I didn't.  The whole setup is an adaptation of concepts taken from different popular design patterns.

Comment: Very cool. Thank you for this answer! This is giving me some ideas.... :-)

Comment: @ArcherBird You are welcome!  This was a fun one to write.  Note: I made some adjustments to the Factory. I forgot to have it return the Character,

Comment: Typo?  "The classes above give are a quick muck-up"

Comment: If C# is an option, then VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) has a range change event; so one could define a range for each column and save a few ops.

Comment: @SMeaden You would not save any operations.  In order to implement your approach you would need to add a NamedRange and a ChangeEventHandler for each column.  Event handlers are not free they are added into the message loop.   When the `NamedRange.Change` event  fire you will still have to find row number to reference the object.  Although it would not save any operations, there may be some very useful applications for it.  Such as, streamline the business logic for a property for all the objects.

Comment: A long time ago, I stumbled [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa239662(v=vs.60)] about object connection. Along with @TinMan's answer, this might give you further ideas.

And then there's that strange beast named [https://www.engram9.info/visual-basic-vba/data-binding-objects-vb-library-to-reference.html] msbind.dll (Microsoft Data Binding Collection))

(Edit) I'm apparently bad at links in comments. :-/

Comment: @HelO'Ween check the help menu below "Add comment" for fixing of links

Comment: @Oliver: that's where I looked in the first palce, but I got the sequence wrong (1. link, 2. description). Looking at it again now, I recon it's the reverse order. So thx for pointing me again there. The ["Learn more about comments"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) has a better notation.

Comment: @HelO'Ween could you redo those links? I’m interested to take a look!

Comment: @ArcherBird [Programming with Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa239662(v=vs.60)) and [Data Binding Objects VB Library to Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa239662(v=vs.60))

Comment: @TinMan to the rescue! :-)

Comment: Thanks for exepting my answer. It's always fun to wins a bounty!

Comment: @TinMan thanks for posting! I’m incorporating some of your answer into my own solution and I will maybe post my own answer too.

Comment: You should post your solution on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).